Why is my JPA repository not saving anything?
I am working with the Roku Dev Tools API to create a remote controller app via a Java Spring Boot backend. I have three JPA repositories: TelevisionRepository, AppsRepository, and AppRepository. My TelevisionRepository saves its entities just fine, but both the AppsRepository and AppRepository fail to do so. I think it might have something to do with these objects getting their attributes from the Roku API call, which returns its data in XML. The "Apps" shares a one-to-many relationship with the "App" object. My intention is to call the Roku API to query for the channels (http://{{rokuIPAddress}}:8060/query/apps) installed on a given television, then save them to the repository. I made my repo for this code public.
I have tried calling my getApps method from my service and controller to get all of the apps on my tv:
// Get apps list for tv
    @GetMapping(path = "/get-apps/{name}")
    public ResponseEntity<Apps> getApps(@PathVariable String name) {
        return appsService.getApps(name);
    }

// Get apps list for tv
    public ResponseEntity<Apps> getApps(String name) {
        Television tele = televisionRepository.findByTelevisionName(name).orElseThrow(() -> new TelevisionNotFoundException());
        log.info(String.format("Requesting apps for %s via: http://%s:8060/query/apps", name, tele.getIpAddress()));
        ResponseEntity<Apps> responseEntity = this.restTemplate.getForEntity("http://" + tele.getIpAddress() + ":8060/query/apps", Apps.class);
        Apps apps = responseEntity.getBody();
        System.out.println(apps.toString());
        for (App app : apps.getApp()) {
            appRepository.save(app);
        }
        appsRepository.save(apps);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(apps);
    }

This implementation fails to save anything to the appRepository and appsRepository.
Here are the classes for Apps and App:
@Entity
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "app")
public class App {

    @Id
    @XmlAttribute(name = "id")
    private String id;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "type")
    private String type;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "version")
    private String version;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Apps apps;
    
    // Constructors, getters and setters

@Entity
@XmlRootElement(name = "apps")
@Table(name = "apps")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Apps {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "apps", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    private List<App> app;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "television_id")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Television television;

    // Constructors, getters and setters

The repositories:
public interface AppRepository extends JpaRepository<App, String> {
}

public interface AppsRepository extends JpaRepository<Apps, Long> {
}

Here are my H2 db configurations:
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.h2.console.enabled=true

Here is an example of what the API call looks in Postman


Are you getting any response from /get-apps/{name} API?

@Jignesh yes I am. It appears to work fine.

What or who takes care of the Transactions?

@AdriaanVeney Were you able to find the root cause. If so, can you please explain?
